# Unable to add data to mySQL database

Tags: android, mysql, server

During my app register process,server returns "Forbidden" when attempting to add user to database. Seems i'm unable to add data to my database or it's not accessible.

I have even tried running this command in mysql console but still same thing :

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: are you try to that using postman. It may help you to detect the problem.

Comment: Are you connecting directly to a MySQL database from your Android app? Or going through an intermediate server-side application?

Comment: Yes it's from my Android app

Comment: If you are accessing MySQL server directly, and with non-root user, make sure that it have permissions to add new user, and grant privileges.